# How can I run a bash in every subfolder of a base folder

Tags: bash, shell, unix, console

I want to 'optimize' all my *.png images and found [this](http://es.kioskea.net/faq/7287-reducir-el-tamano-de-imagenes-png) so I made the bash as it says with:

```
#!/bin/bash    
pngnq -vf -s1 *.png    
rename -f 's/-nq8.png$/.png/' *.png    
optipng -o7 *.png
```

And here I have 2 problems:

The first one is that the second line (rename) does nothing... it is supposed to change all the images named `[name]-nq8.png` which is the result of the first line of the bash to the original name

The second and main problem is: I have a folder named ImagesFolder and inside I have other folders with more *.pngs  and I want to run this bash in every subfolder of ImagesFolder but I don't know how to do it (I'm new in unix and shellscripts and so on) and what I tried didn't work or was a mess...

To understand it better what I have is something like:

```
ImagesFolder
  |-Folder1
  |     |- Folder12
  |     |      |-20 images here
  |     |- Folder13
  |     |      |- 10 images more here
  |     |- 5 images here 
  |-more images
```

And I want the script to run from ImagesFolder

Thank you so much!

Comment: There are no "folders" in a directory hierarchy.  There are only directories, subdirectories, and files.  You may name a directory "Folder1", but it remains a directory.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: folder is a synonym for directory....

Comment: @Karoly, no, a folder is an artifact of a gui.  Folders contain files (or some other non-technical marketing happy nonsense way of thinking about the internal structure of the filesystem), but directories do not.  Directories merely contain links to files, and it is best not to blur the distinction.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: It's widely used outside of GUI context. Let's agree to disagree.

Comment: Hi, @WilliamPursell yes sorry that was my fault, I said folder meaning directory because in the fedora where I work you create a new folder not a new directory

Comment: Unfortunately it is often used outside of a gui context, but it is done so incorrectly.  I have no objection whatsoever to disagreeing with incorrect usage, but will endeavor to correct it on occasion.  This is one of those times!

Comment: @WilliamPursell I don't use the word folder much because I too feel that "folder" is more of a GUI thing, but I don't mind if people do. I can't think of any benefit to maintaining a distinction between the two.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I dont like folder, I prefer directory but it was the first word that appeared on my mind and thought it was the normal one cause as I said I just created one on my OS  but its nice to know it, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would probably do is:

1) Fix the script so it takes args instead of the globbing in the current directory:

```
#!/bin/bash    
pngnq -vf -s1 "$1"    
mv "${1%.png}-nq8.png" "$1"
optipng -o7 "$1"
```

2) Test it that it works as intended

3) Run it with `find` and `xargs` in parallel (I bet you have a multicore processor)

```
find . -name '*.png' -print0 | xargs -0 -P6 -n1 the_script
```

The script could be inline too. But my main point its, use parallelism if you're on multicore. It will speed things up a lot.

Comment: it works fine and so quickly! I'll see later what xargs do exactly but thank you so much! Do you why rename does nothing in my case? I'm woking on fedora12

Comment: It's the `-P6` argument that tells it to always have 6 processes running.  You can change the number and/or add the `-n some_number` option to tweak how many arguments will be passed to each invocation of script (it'll be as many as possible by default). CPU intensive tasks like yours are a prime candidate for parallelization.

Comment: The `-v` (verbose) option to rename might be useful for debugging. Have you tested the script on a single argument?

Comment: @PSkocik It is because you are using the original filename which no longer exists as the arg for rename.

Comment: @User112638726 Thanks! I hadn't given it much though. It should work now.

Comment: Now does soemthign so so strange. it goes to 1 sub folder, then do the work on an image (there is no -nq8.png visible there so I could think it works fine) but then stops so... its like it just applies to this 1 png and its always the same O.o

Comment: @PSkocik how do u debug it and how do u use -v?

Comment: @PSkocik if I change all "$1" to "$@" as u have it before it works (the mv still does nothing but at least it doesn't stop

Answer (score 2):

In general, the tool you want to use when you wish to do something recursively on a directory tree is `find`.  If your script is named `foo`,

```
find /path/of/base/dir -type f -name '*.png' -exec foo {} \;
```

will invoke the script on every regular file in the directory tree whose name ends in `.png`.