# command rename does not work on my bash script

Tags: bash, shell, command, rename

Yesterday I made a question here: [How can I run a bash in every subfolder of a base folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457792/how-can-i-run-a-bash-in-every-subfolder-of-a-base-folder) and my main problem was solved but I have another one: I don't know why but the rename command does NOTHING if I try to use it recursively. I've tried all different options they told me and other I found and if I run the rename on a single directory it works fine (so the line its ok) but can't make it work recursively.

The question of optimizing images doen't matter now cause I changed the script to do it first. Now I have all the images like this way: image.png (which is the oriniginal) and image-nq8.png which is the optimized one)

What I want now is to have the optimized one with the name of the original, and the original deleted. But as any of my attempts on it, they all fail and I don't know why.

I made an script: scriptloop

```
  for i in $(find /path/to/start/ -name "*.png");do     
   rename -nq8.png .png *-nq8*
  done
```

and call it this way: `./scriptloop`

and tried too using: `find . -name '*-nq8.png' -print0 | xargs -0 -P6 -n1 scriptOneLine`

with this inside scriptOneLine:  `rename -nq8.png .png *-nq8*`

Note: as I said if I run `rename -nq8.png .png *-nq8*` on a directory it works but I can't make it work recursive. Any idea of why or what am I doing wrong? (I'm on fedora)

Thank you so much

Comment: That usage of `find` in a loop is incorrect and unsafe for many legal filenames. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor for more information. That `xargs` attempt is much better and assuming the script accepts a file name as the first argument it should have worked. What about it did not?

Comment: The problem with your `find` loop attempt is that you aren't operating on the `$i` file in the loop. Your `rename` command is operating on the contents of the `*-nq8*` glob (current directory) for every file that `find` finds.

Comment: thanks @EtanReisner, I understand you. But this is so new for me and I 'm so lost. How can I do it then?

Comment: Recall that *nix has also `mv -R`

Comment: @boardrider `-R`? I can't find that documented anywhere.

Comment: You want to use `"$i"` as the argument to `rename` in that loop instead of the `*-nq8*` glob. (Though as I said in my first comment that `for`/`find` loop is an anti-pattern and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Oh sorry I writte it bad, If I use the second call then the script has only the rename line. I'll edit now and correct it sorry. I want to remark that these examples are from the help I got in the other topic cause I don't know so much about unix commands (and that's why I'm asking here how to solve that problem)

Comment: Mea culpa @Etan: my cerebral cortex mixed `mv` with `cp`.